# Why mutableMapOf returns nullable?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, nullable

I wrote a simple code block to store `fragments` with `ids` in `Map`. The `value` and `key` of map is initialized as non-nullable but when I want to get them as `key` and `value`, it gives `nullable` type data. So, I don't understand why? Is there any other type of map that returns `non-nullable` data in `Kotlin`?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible that there is no value for key [position], which will make it return `null`:

> ```
> abstract operator fun get(key: K): V?
> ```
>
> Returns the value corresponding to the given key, or null if such a key is not present in the map.

Answer (score 3):

@nhaarman is right, but you can use `getValue(key)` that return non-nullable but throw `NoSuchElementException` if not found.

```
/**
 * Returns the value for the given [key] or throws an exception if there is no such key in the map.
 *
 * If the map was created by [withDefault], resorts to its `defaultValue` provider function
 * instead of throwing an exception.
 *
 * @throws NoSuchElementException when the map doesn't contain a value for the specified key and
 * no implicit default value was provided for that map.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
public fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.getValue(key: K): V = getOrImplicitDefault(key)
```

Comment: Before your answer, I wrote this. : ```` override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = (fragmentsAndIds[position]) ?: throw NullPointerException()```` 
 It does similiar thing. But your option is cleaner and short. I will use it. thanks

Comment: Yeah it does the same thing. By the way, you can write `override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = (fragmentsAndIds[position])!!`. The `!!` will throw `NullPointerException` if null ;)